# how can I have two different root in tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

how can I have two different root in tortoise svn? For example, I want to keep c# projects in one root directory and android projects in another root directory. I know I can keep all the projects in one root directory, but still it would be great to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for isn't possible.

If you have directories like

```
projects-c#
```

and

```
projects-android
```

then you have two choices:

A) you create **two** SVN repositories; each one using that directory as "root"

B) you create **one** SVN repository; but then you need something like:

```
trunk/projects-c#
trunk/projects-android
```

In other words: you can't have it *both* ways at the same time. Either A), or B); but not AB)

And if you prefer A) or B) ... really depends on your local setup. For example on the need of people working on A) stuff to look into B) and vice versa. One repository: everybody can easily get to the other stuff; whereas two repositories make it easier to **separate** those things.

And please note: tortoise is just one of many clients that exist for SVN. In that sense you are not asking a "SVN client" question, but a question about the features/functions of SVN itself.

And maybe you want to read about SVN itself, like this [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.importing.html).